# SQL Server Report how to create multiple groups with hidden details

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting, report-builder

I have created a report that has multiple rows returned from one query.

I have a chart that is created for all the row and I have it grouped on the server location.  the group properties of the details group i have visibility set to hidden and set to display when toggled.

I want to do this for another column so there is another nested group that can be toggled.

When I try to add a child group under the details group it tells me *`cannot group inside detail`*.

Is it not possible to add another group that can be toggled to the report?

Comment: check this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954323/trying-to-add-sub-row-group-inside-parent-but-flush-left-in-the-nested-cell and https://direit.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/ssrs-create-child-group-in-same-column-below-parent/

Comment: Yes, this helped me figure out how i should do it.  Didnt go with those exact examples but it helped me find my way.  Thanks.